# Is there a program to automatically save/restore snapshots of my source tree locally?

Tags: version-control

Is there a program that saves state of my source tree once in a while and lets me come back to a previous state easily? I imagine a combination of watchman and some script or program, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably most of IDEs has a built-in local history support, which allows you to restore any saved state of the project. At least PhpStorm has this feature (and probably the whole IntelliJ family). AFAIK Netbeans support its to. So I would start from searching some decent IDE, since this will give you the best integration with your editor.

If you don't like IDEs, you should be more specific about your requirements. At current state some backup tool (like `duplicity` or `rdiff-backup`) + cron should do the job.